# DynamoDb retrieve data Order by descending order and then use pagination like sql syntax

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I am facing problem to retrieve records in descending order with pagination limit from amazon dynamodb as in mysql. 
Now I am using the following script, but it gives unordered list of records. I need the last inserted id is on top.

```
$limit      =   10;
$total = 0;
$start_key = null;
$params = array('TableName' => 'event','AttributesToGet' =>array('id','interactiondate','repname','totalamount','fooding','nonfooding','pdfdocument','isMultiple','payment_mode','interaction_type','products','programTitle','venue','workstepId','foodingOther','interaction_type_other'), 'ScanFilter'=> array('manufacturername' => array("ComparisonOperator" => "EQ", "AttributeValueList" => array(array("S" => "$manufacturername")))),'Limit'=>$limit );
$itemsArray = array();
$itemsArray = array();
$finalItemsArray = array(); 
$finalCRMRecords = array();
do{
if(!empty($start_key)){             
$params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $start_key->getArrayCopy();
}
$response = $this->Amazon->Dynamodb->scan($params);     
if ($response->status == 200) {
$counter = (string) $response->body->Count;
$total += $counter;
foreach($response->body->Items as $itemsArray){
$finalItemsArray[]  =   $itemsArray;    
}
if($total>$limit){
$i =1;
foreach($response->body->Items as $items){
$finalItemsArray[]      =   $items;
if($i == $limit){
$start_key = $items->id->{AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER}->to_array();
$finalCRMRecords['data']    =   $finalItemsArray;
$finalCRMRecords['start_key']   =   $start_key;
break;
}
$i++;
}
}elseif($total<$limit){
$start_key = $response->body->LastEvaluatedKey->to_array();
}else{
$finalCRMRecords['data']    =   $finalItemsArray;
if ($response->body->LastEvaluatedKey) {
$start_key =$response->body->LastEvaluatedKey->to_array();
break;
} else {
$start_key = null;
}
$finalCRMRecords['start_key']   =   $start_key; 
}
}       
}while($start_key);
```

Regards

Sandeep Kumar Sinha

Answer (score 1):

A `Scan` operation in DynamoDB can not change the sorting of the returned items. Also is `Scan` a pretty expensive operation as it always requires to read the whole table.

If you want to take advantage of DynamoDB, here's one advice:

> Instead of **looking** for information, try to just **find** it.

In the sense of, use *lookups* instead of *scan/query* to get the information you need.

As an example, if you have a table that stores *Events*. Just store all events in that table, with their *EventId* as `HashKey`. Then you can have a second table *EventLookups* to store  lookups to *EventIds*. In the *EventLookups* table you could put an `Item` like `LookupId: LATEST-EVENT` referencing some `EventId: ...`. Every time you insert new events you can update the *LATEST-EVENT* entry to point to a newer Event. Or use a SET to store the latest 50 EventIds events in one Item.

-mathias